# Docker overlay folder eats up GB of data

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

My docker setup is as follows:

Jenkins 
web environment
mongo(DB)
Elastic search

I did a clean up by removing all the images and containers and created fresh new images and containers

But after a few months I ran out of space on my AWS EC2 instance where this is hosted.

```
docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL     ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              6         6                   4.272GB             0B (0%)
Containers          6         6                   1.418GB             0B (0%)
Local Volumes       2         2                   74.9kB              0B (0%)
Build Cache         0         0                   0B                  0B


docker info
Containers: 6
 Running: 5
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 53
Server Version: 18.09.4
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-1087-aws
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.303GiB
Name: ip-10-167-186-26
ID: EAHN:WAGM:PDI3:VE4R:VL2P:KZMN:S766:KF7J:ERYW:AKOM:JQFZ:E64I
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

In the overlay folder when I do 
sudo du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr

Comment: Currently I have no working method which will stop overlay from filling up.
But now I just stop the docker containers and do a ```docker system prune -a ``` whenever overlay folder fills up.